# Getting point coordinates from `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates

I have this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
self.ax = plt.subplot(111)
cords = self.get_list_of_cords()
plt.plot(cords[0], cords[1], 'o', color='b')
plt.show()
```

I want to get back coordinates from my plot. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do that. I know it may be silly, but seriously I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the coordinates from the data with the `get_data()` method of the lines2D object, see [Docu](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_data):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot(111)
li = ax.plot([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,4], 'o-', color='b')
print li[0].get_data()
```

gives

```
(array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 4]))
```

If you cannot save the list of lines directly with the plot command, you can get it from the *ax* object by means of the `ax.get_lines()` method.